# OpenAI Whisper cannot handle past a few seconds of IOS recording

Tags: speech-to-text, openai-api, whisper

I am sending audio recordings to the OpenAI Whisper API and cannot get mobile recordings to accept past a few seconds of data, I have no idea why. Desktop audio recordings function perfectly fine but whenever I try on my phone the transcriptions only get a word or two.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  --form 'file=@C:\Users\katra\Desktop\audio.wav' \
  --form model=whisper-1
```

If anyone can tell me what to do that would be great have been stumped and cannot find anyone with this issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this problem the issue is that you're sending the data in a multi-part form format and/or base64 encoded. Which looks like the image attached [base-encoded-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IRst.png) and this is how a your multi-part form looks like [multi-part form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0cZ1.png). So before you can send it to whisper you need to decode it , then parse the multi-part form to get everything after the web-kit form boundary-- . So you can use a built-in python library called cgi and extract the audio.  `cgi.FieldStorage(fp=BytesIO(base64.b64decode(event["body"])), headers={'content-type': content_type}, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST'})`

is what I used. This was however in a lambda function, so of course you won't have "event"

Here's the lambda code snippet i used

```
content_type = event["headers"]["content-type"]
form_data = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=BytesIO(base64.b64decode(event["body"])), headers={'content-type': content_type}, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST'})

if "audio" not in form_data:
    print("Error: No audio data received.")  # Logging error for no audio data
    return {
        'statusCode': 400,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST'
        },
        'body': json.dumps('No audio data received.')
    }

# Extracting audio data from parsed form data
audio_data = form_data["audio"].file.read()
```

Comment: Sadly did not fix the IOS issue

Comment: I am facing same issue with iphone browser when using open ai transcription in my react app.
const getTranscript = async (recordedBlob) => {
    try {
      const audioFile = new File([recordedBlob], "audio.mp3", {
        type: "audio/mp3",
      });
      const transcript = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
        model: "whisper-1",
        file: audioFile,
        response_format: "text",
      });
      return transcript;
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  };